# Cannot cast to class . . . are unnamed module of loader

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Priority Queue ADT from scratch using a linked list implementation. In the priority queue I need to insert Jobs and the Jobs have to be executed in order of priority. The priority ADT that I constructed was from my Java book, and my Job class was created by me. I am able to insert all the jobs into the priority queue but when I try to removeMin() I get a cannot cast class... error.

This is my method for taking an array, putting them in the queue and removing them.

```
public static void executeJobs(Job[] jobInputArray) {

    SortedPriorityQueue pq = new SortedPriorityQueue();
    
    for(int j = 0; j < jobInputArray.length; j++) {
        pq.insert(jobInputArray[j].getFinalPriority(), jobInputArray[j]);
        jobInputArray[j].setEntryTime(j+1);
    }
    
    int cycles = 0;
    
    while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        Job currentJob = (Job) pq.removeMin();
        System.out.println(currentJob.getJobName());
    }
}
```

The problem arises on my: Job currentJob = (Job) pq.removeMin(); line.

This is my SortedPriorityQueue class:

```
public static class SortedPriorityQueue<K,V> extends AbstractPriorityQueue<K,V>{
private PositionalList<Entry<K,V>> list = new LinkedPositionalList<>();

public SortedPriorityQueue() { super(); }
public SortedPriorityQueue(Comparator<K> comp) {super(comp);}

public Entry<K,V> insert(K key, V value) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    checkKey(key);
    Entry<K,V> newest = new PQEntry<>(key,value);
    Position<Entry<K,V>> walk = list.last();
    
    while(walk != null && compare(newest, walk.getElement()) < 0)
        walk = list.before(walk);
    if(walk == null)
        list.addFirst(newest);
    else
        list.addAfter(walk, newest);
    return newest;
}
public Entry<K,V> min(){
    if (list.isEmpty()) return null;
    return list.first().getElement();
}

public Entry<K,V> removeMin(){
    if(list.isEmpty()) return null;
    return list.remove(list.first());
}
public int size() {return list.size();}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class helloworld.helpers$AbstractPriorityQueue$PQEntry cannot be cast to class helloworld.Job (helloworld.helpers$AbstractPriorityQueue$PQEntry and helloworld.Job are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: What type does removeMin return? What are K and V instantiated to in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeMin` returns an `Entry<K,V>`, not a `Job`. It cannot be cast to `Job`. The implementation for `Entry` is missing, but I assume it has a `value()` or `getValue()` method:

```
Job currentJob = (Job) pq.removeMin().getValue();
```

Comment: holy crap i am so stupid... I was literally playing around with that all day. I don't know why it didnt click with me

Comment: @FalseOccasion if you instantiate your queue with `new SortedPriorityQueue<KeyType, Job>()`, then you don't have to cast at all. `getValue()` would already return the correct type. Don't use raw types if you can avoid them.

Comment: Gotcha! Quick question but is there a way to iterate over the Priority Queue that I made to search for a value using an augmented for loop?

Comment: @FalseOccasion: Have your class implement the [`Iterable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)